# Problem with class creation specific to the below problem

Tags: java, class, greedy

I have a problem in a Java coding problem, and I could use a little bit of help in understanding the thought process of a condition mentioned in the problem (highlighted below).

The goal of this question is to design a cash register program. Your register currently has the following notes/coins within it:

One Pence: .01
Two Pence: .02
Five Pence: .05
Ten Pence: .10
Twenty Pence: .20
Fifty Pence: .50
One Pound: 1
Two Pounds: 2
Five Pounds: 5
Ten Pounds: 10
Twenty Pounds: 20
Fifty Pounds: 50

The aim of the program is to calculate the change that has to be returned to the customer with the least number of coins/notes. Note that the expectation is to have an object-oriented solution - **think about creating classes for better reusability**.

Now there is a similar post for this question on this platform, but I want to know how to use classes in this problem instead of hardcoding the denominations? I would highly appreciate if anyone can shed some light on it! I have written the following code for this, any help on changing this according to the condition above will be appreciated:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
  /**
   * Iterate through each line of input.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

    try {
        double purchasePrice = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
        double cash = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
        Main.calculateChange(purchasePrice, cash);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  public static void calculateChange(double purchasePrice, double cash) {
    
    float cashBack = (float) (cash - purchasePrice);
    
    if (cashBack < 0) {
      System.out.println("ERROR");
      return ;
    }
    else if (cashBack == 0){
      System.out.println(0);
    }
    StringBuilder change = new StringBuilder();

        while (cashBack > 0.01) {
            if (cashBack >= 50.0) {
                change.append("Fifty Pounds");
                cashBack -= 50.0;
            } else if (cashBack >= 20.0) {
                change.append("Twenty Pounds");
                cashBack -= 20.0; 
            } else if (cashBack >= 10.0) {
                change.append("Ten Pounds");
                cashBack -= 10.0;
            } else if (cashBack >= 5.0) {
                change.append("Five Pounds");
                cashBack -= 5.0;
            } else if (cashBack >= 2.0) {
                change.append("Two Pounds");
                cashBack -= 2.0;
            } else if (cashBack >= 1.0) {
                change.append("One Pound");
                cashBack -= 1.0;
            } else if (cashBack >= 0.5) {
                change.append("Fifty Pence");
                cashBack -= 0.5;
            } else if (cashBack >= 0.20) {
                change.append("Twenty Pence");
                cashBack -= 0.20;
            } else if (cashBack >= 0.1) {
                change.append("Ten Pence");
                cashBack -= 0.1;
            } else if (cashBack >= 0.05) {
                change.append("Five Pence");
                cashBack -= 0.05;
            } else if (cashBack >= 0.02) {
                change.append("Two Pence");
                cashBack -= 0.02;
            } else {
                change.append("One Pence");
                cashBack -= 0.01;
            }
            change.append(", ");
        }
        change.setLength(change.length() - 2);

        System.out.println(change.toString());
    // Access your code here. Feel free to create other classes as required
  }

}
```

Comment: Always please share your thoughts on the design first. Give it a try and then post the question.

Comment: @Suman I had hardcoded the problem using the denominations, and all test cases are running fine. But since the question has introduced this additional layer, I currently don't have any ideas as to how I can achieve this. If you can provide a direction, I shall be grateful

Comment: You should follow the bolded advice in the question. In this case you could make classes of anything you want like `MoneyType`,  `CashRegister`, etc. In fact, you'll strictly be avoiding a bunch of static methods in the main class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete solution is here:

Coin class: Holds a coin value and its name.

```
public class Coin {

    double value;
    String name;

    public Coin(double value, String name) {
        this.value = value;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Cash Register class: This holds different types of coins in descending order.

```
public class CashRegister {

    LinkedHashSet<Coin> coins = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public String calculateChange(double purchasePrice, double cash) {

        double cashBack = cash - purchasePrice;

        if (cashBack < 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            return "";
        }

        StringBuilder change = new StringBuilder();

        while (cashBack > 0) {
            Iterator<Coin> iterator = coins.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Coin coin = iterator.next();
                int count = 0;
                while (cashBack >= coin.getValue()) {
                    count++;
                    cashBack -= coin.getValue();
                }
                if (count > 0) {
                    change.append(count).append(" " + coin.getName());
                    change.append("\n");
                }
            }
        }
        return change.toString();
    }

    public LinkedHashSet<Coin> init() {
        coins.add(new Coin(50, "Fifty Pound"));
        coins.add(new Coin(20, "Twenty Pound"));
        coins.add(new Coin(10, "Ten Pound"));
        coins.add(new Coin(5, "Five Pound"));
        coins.add(new Coin(2, "Two Pound"));
        coins.add(new Coin(1, "One Pound"));
        coins.add(new Coin(0.5, "Fifty Pence"));
        coins.add(new Coin(0.2, "Twenty Pence"));
        coins.add(new Coin(0.1, "Ten Pence"));
        coins.add(new Coin(0.05, "Five Pence"));
        coins.add(new Coin(0.02, "Two Pence"));
        coins.add(new Coin(0.01, "One Pence"));
        return coins;
    }
}
```

Instantiation and invocation of the cash register to get change:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
        try {
            // Initialise cash register.
            CashRegister cashRegister = new CashRegister();
            cashRegister.init();

            double purchasePrice = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
            double cash = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());

            // Calculate change.
            String result = cashRegister.calculateChange(purchasePrice, cash);
            System.out.println(result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Any denominations of coins can be added in Cash register via the *init()* method. You can also add a lot of other features to Cash register like

- Maintain a balance.
- Support to add new denominations dynamically.
- Support to remove denomination dynamically.